# What is the difference between 2 pieces of code?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game and I don't know how to make changes to an array

If I do it this way It wont change my array but if I replace i to a and j to b( in here System.out.print(matrice[a][b] + "|"); it changes from a blank space to an X and I dont know why

```
package joc;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class jocxo {



    public static char[][] matrice = new char[3][3];
    public static Scanner Int = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int a;
    public static int b;



    public static void main(String[] args){
        board();
        game();
    }

    public static void board()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.println();
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                matrice[i][j] ='_';
                if ( j==0 )
                    System.out.print("|");


                System.out.print(matrice[i][j] + "|");

            }
        }               
     }
    public static void game(){

        a = Int.nextInt() - 1; 
        b = Int.nextInt() - 1; 
        if (matrice[a][b] == '_') 
        {   
            matrice[a][b] ='X';     
            board();


        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `board()` again after you got your input.
check out what `board()` is doing.

```
matrice[i][j] = '_';
```

You are setting `matrice[a][b]` to `X`. Afterwards you print your board with the board function. But since you are using it to initialize your board aswell you are basicly resetting the array to only contain `_`.

you should create a method like `initizalize()` that your code could look like the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    initialize();
    board();
    game();
}

public static void board() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (j == 0)
                System.out.print("|");
            System.out.print(matrice[i][j] + "|");
        }
    }
}

private static void initialize() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            matrice[i][j] = '_';
        }
    }
}

public static void game() {
    a = Int.nextInt() - 1;
    b = Int.nextInt() - 1;
    if (matrice[a][b] == '_') {
        matrice[a][b] = 'X';
        board();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static char[][] matrice = new char[3][3];
    public static Scanner Int = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int a;
    public static int b;



    public static void main(String[] args){
        initBoard();
        game();
        displayBoard();
    }
    public static void initBoard(){
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.println();
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                matrice[i][j] ='_';
                if ( j==0 )
                    System.out.print("|");


                System.out.print(matrice[i][j] + "|");

            }
        }


        }// board close
    public static void displayBoard(){
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.println();
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){                 
                if ( j==0 )
                    System.out.print("|");
                System.out.print(matrice[i][j] + "|");

            }
        }


        }// board close
    public static void game(){

        a = Int.nextInt() - 1; 
        b = Int.nextInt() - 1;
        System.out.println(matrice[a][b] == '_');
        if (matrice[a][b] == '_') 
        {   matrice[a][b] ='X';
        }
    }// game close.
```

Comment: you calling the board which initialize your array again... changed the code and posted it